# Is there a way to get device serial number on android 11 and above?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, flutter-dependencies

Nothing that I have tried works on android 11 and earlier versions.

Because I tried using different approach but it doesn't seem to be able to work on android 11 and earlier versions.

Even if is something that can only work on debug mode...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should state why you need 'device serial number' and list out what "different approaches" did you try.

Comment: I want to use a serial number to track the records stored from different devices, because each record must be identified using that serial number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids
Even with a library, the ID will be null due to privacy reasons, consider resettable identifiers like Firebase App Installation Id if you need to track the app instance instead of the user.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get unique identifier ...

in Android: using **unique_identifier** to get IMEI

`unique_identifier: ^0.0.3
String  identifier =await UniqueIdentifier.serial;`

in IOS: Apple no longer allows you to retrieve the IMEI or any other device identification

Comment: So there's no library for native android?

Comment: yes and i also just checked the docs, now even with external libs you won't be able to get the anything for privacy reasons

Comment: Thank you. I thought maybe there is a way to do that on debug without a certification, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did my research and read the google documentation about their recent security features, what I can say is that you can not bypass this security feature without a certification from google. The certification is not just given to any developer, but organizations that have control and use Android OS (this includes your android mobile phones brands), not just android app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).